# Code Signing Failure Blackberry Ant tools

Tags: blackberry, cordova, code-signing

I am using phonegap and sencha touch to build mobile applications. I have successfully built Android and iOS application. When it comes to blackberry application, I am using the procedure given at phonegap docs. http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-BlackBerry-WebWorks

I can able build and deploy application on to the simulator. But when it comes to code signing it always getting failed.

When I run the command "ant build" the signature tools pops up and closes successfully, I even get 75 emails to my inbox.

Note: I have only sigtool.csk and sigtool.db. Is this the problem?

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well at last I got the solution. If you get a code signing error which does not specify any details, just uninstall and reinstall Java, Blackberry web works and Ripple emulator in the same order. It works for me.